# State-of the art stream-oriented AES encryption in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, aes

As a Python beginner I am looking for good crypto examples in python. Until now every code snippets I found were strange - no real padding and totally uncomfortable regarding the block size. 
As I am processing large data in stream form I expect a comfortable block size handling, too.

In **Java** everything would be solved using the following two lines (:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); // or better "AES/GCM/NoPadding"
stream = new CipherInputStream(cipher);
```

What do I have to use when doing the same in Python (doesn't matter which crypto library)?

Comment: Wouldn't call `CipherInputStream` state of the art directly - it (used to?) shuffle `BadPaddingException`'s including authentication tag related ones - under the table. I'll test how it fares nowadays, but I'm afraid it won't behave too well. But OK, the point is to stream AES in Python.

Comment: No, padding is only applied at the end of the stream. If a read operation requests a number of bytes that do not match regarding the cipher block size the unused bytes are held internally in the CipherInputStream until they are requested/read.

Comment: Ah, [it's fixed now](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061619). Robert, you really do not have to explain crypto to me.

Comment: Why not try and create your own `RawIOBase` derivative?

Comment: Here's one, you'd possibly have to refactor the M2Crypto out of it though: [`aesstream`](https://github.com/mbr/aesstream/blob/master/aesstream.py)

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: Please remember that I am a Python beginner - therefore I prefer using something existing instead of re-inventing a wheel... The aesstream you linked looks nice. However I read that M2crypto is not Python3 compatible.

Comment: Officially reference recommendations are off topic though and if you cannot find it with an Internet search, chances are slim that you find anything by asking it here.

Comment: What do you mean with "reference recommendations"? I am searching for working code. If the sample code references an existing library/module plus shows how to use it this is an valid answer.